# Object doesn't follow path in a perfect curve

Tags: animation, particles, constraints

I want to make an object that follows a circle and emits a light streak using a particle system. The problem is that the object does not seem to follow the circle perfectly. It seems to follow a low poly version of the circle since I see edges in the trajectory. How can I make the trajectory perfectly smooth?

[image]

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the cache of the emiter, select the curve and in *Object Data > Shape*, increase the *Resolution* value:

[image]